# How can I delete PHP cookies without refreshing the browser?

Tags: php, cookies

I want to delete a cookie but find the browser must be refreshed or another link clicked for the cookie to go away. I have used header(..) in PHP.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['auth_key'])){setcookie("auth_key", "", time() - 3600);}
header("Location: ../login.php");
```

When I get to the login page, the cookie outputs, but on refresh it disappears, or if I go to another link from there, it disappears.

I would like the cookie removed without any user interaction and deleted before the server loads login.php.

Any help would be appreciated.

This answer is:

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE['auth_key'])){setcookie("auth_key", "", 1,'/');}
```

because I set the cookie with a slash '/'. I used this to delete it, and it works now. However, it was odd that the cookie was still deleted on refresh.

Comment: don't use relative times for deleting cookies. peoples' clocks can be WAY off. for deleting a cookie, always use a fixed time value of `1`.

Comment: Tried this but the cookie is deleting my way (and yours). It is the fact of getting the browser to accept this.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the cookie (using this code) at the start of login.php instead of this redirect page.

Comment: I delete the cookie on both logout and login page and still no luck.

Comment: Still no lock? Found out anything?

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting maybe a timeout period and then use Javascript to initiate an AJAX request to a server-side page to delete the cookie in question.

Comment: The cookie needs to be deleted immediately on logout, as it affects the login page menu.Do you mean put an ajax script on the login.php perhaps, to replicate the refresh action.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer I found was to set the cookie with a "/":

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['auth_key'])) {
    setcookie("auth_key", "", 1, '/');
}
```

I used this to delete all cookies and it works now. However the cookie is still deleted on refresh.